# Set property with whitespace with py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to set a property with a value which could have with space.I'm using py2neo and I wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
name = mention['name']
screen_name = mention['screen_name']
id = mention['id']

graph.run(
  'MATCH (f) '
  'WHERE EXISTS(f.account_id) AND f.account_id=\'' + id + '\' '
  'SET f.name=\'' + re.escape(name) + '\', f.screen_name=\'@' + screen_name + '\' '                                                     
  'RETURN null'
)
```

How can I solve ? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I get this error

````SyntaxError: Invalid input ' ': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 1, column 122 (offset: 121)) "MATCH (f {graph_information: ['admin','twitter']}) WHERE EXISTS(f.account_id) AND f.account_id='18511142' SET f.name='So\ Fain' f.screen_name='@sofain' RETURN null"````

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the values (including the problematic value for `name`) as parameters. That avoids messy issues with the Python and Cypher parsers (and escaping the string value should also not be necessary).

This may work for you:

```
graph.run(
  'MATCH (f) '
  'WHERE f.account_id=$id '
  'SET f.name=$name, f.screen_name=$screen_name',
  {"id": mention['id'], "name": mention['name'], "screen_name": '@'+mention['screen_name']}
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, However, I solved with this code. I think it's a quite similar with yours ````mentions =tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][0]
            query = \
                'WITH {json} as data ' \
                'MATCH (f) ' \
                'WHERE ' \
                '\'' + usr + '\' IN f.graph_information AND \'twitter\' IN f.graph_information AND ' \
                'EXISTS(f.account_id) AND f.account_id=data.id ' \
                'SET f.name=data.name, f.screen_name=\'@\' + data.screen_name RETURN null'
            graph.run(query, json=mentions)````

Answer (score 0):

> P.S: I assume you are trying to set the property **screen_name** with
>   space.

You placed space after `\'` (single quote), It should be before it:

```
graph.run(
  'MATCH (f) '
  'WHERE EXISTS(f.account_id) AND f.account_id=\'' + id + '\''
  'SET f.name=\'' + re.escape(name) + '\', f.screen_name=\'@' + screen_name + ' \''                                                     
  'RETURN null'
)
```

Comment: sorry the property which could have the white space is *name*. I get the error ````yntaxError: Invalid input ' ': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 1, column 122 (offset: 121)) "MATCH (f {graph_information: ['admin','twitter']}) WHERE EXISTS(f.account_id) AND f.account_id='18511142' SET f.name='So\ Fain' f.screen_name='@sofain' RETURN null```` if, for example, ````name='So\ Fain'````